# How to load an images to imageview in android animation?

Tags: android, animation

I have done as follow

```
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animation_iv);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.loadinganim);
AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();
animationDrawable.start();
```

I have copy image in loading.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:oneshot="false">  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/v1" android:duration="160" />  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/v4" android:duration="160" />  
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/v7" android:duration="160" />  
</animation-list>
```

it get promblem in galaxy note.if any one have idea please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getDrawable(R.drawable.loading);

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading);
    final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground(); 
    startAnimation(frameAnimation);
```

And startAnimation method is:

```
  public void startAnimation(final AnimationDrawable frameAnimation){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run(){
            // some code that runs outside the ui thread.
            frameAnimation.start();
        }
    }).start();
  }
```

I think running the animation on a thread other than the UI thread will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
AnimationDrawable imageAnimation;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading);
    imageAnimation=(AnimationDrawable) image.getDrawable();

 }

public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    imageAnimation.start();
  }
```